# Can't focus on React input

Tags: reactjs

Having some trouble trying to focus in on an element. I have a mapped array function that spits out html with inputs. It is possible to have multiple id's, so I want to set the ref to be 'type' + Id. The two possible types are `task` and `subtask`. When I try access via `this.refs.{refValue}.focus()` I get a `Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined`

Here's my jsx:

```
<input className="ui-input-text" type="text" ref="subTask + {subTask.Id}" onChange={this.handleSubTaskChange.bind(this, indx, idx)} value={subTask.Name} />
```

Here's where I get my error

```
        var subTaskRef = 'subTask' + subTaskId;
        this.refs.subTaskRef.focus();
```

The variable `subTaskId` is correct, I have verified that. Perhaps I am setting the ref incorrectly?

**EDIT**

After following @Ori Drori's answer, here's some more code:

```
class Tasks extends React.Component {
focusTasks: [],
focusSubTasks: [],
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        editableTasks: [],
        editableSubTasks: [], 

        tasks: [],
        subTasks: [],            
        plannerId: this.props.plannerId,
    };

    var state = this.state;


}
```

and (part) of my render method

```
render() {
    const tasks = this.state.tasks.map((task, idx) => {
        var editable = this.state.editableTasks.filter(id => id === task.Id).length > 0;
        var editableSubTasks = this.state.editableSubTasks;
        const subTaskComponents = task.SubTasks.map((subTask, indx) => 
            <li key={subTask.Id} className="list-group-item" style={{minHeight: '50px', border: 0, backgroundColor: 'rgba(127,191,63,.42)'}}>
                    <div className="pull-left" style={{width: '50%'}}>
                        <!-- Pay attention to this line -->{editableSubTasks.filter(id => id === subTask.Id).length > 0 ? <input className="ui-input-text" type="text" ref={ (ref) => this.focusSubTasks[subTask.Id] = ref }  onChange={this.handleSubTaskChange.bind(this, indx, idx)} value={subTask.Name} /> : <span>{subTask.Name}</span>}
                    </div>
                    <div className="pull-right" style={{marginTop: '-5px', width: '50%'}}>
                        <div className="pull-right">
                             <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={() => { this.EditSubTask(task.Id, subTask.Id)}}>{editableSubTasks.filter(id => id === subTask.Id).length > 0  ? <i className="fa fa-check"></i> : <i className="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </li>
        );
```

Here's where the issue seems to be (won't build)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just using jQuery, it's much easier when it's one line of code. Not sure if what I'm doing is too complicated for this, but I ended up setting an id on the inputs, and just calling `$(el).focus()` to solve this problem. Unless someone has a working example, I will update this SO.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ref` callback just to set a property on the class is a common pattern for accessing DOM elements and React creators recommend to use this pattern instead of `this.refs.myRef` pattern.

---

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  // ..

  render() {
    return (

      <input ref={(thisEl) => { this['name' /* + subTask.Id */] = thisEl }} />
    )
  }
}
```

Now you can just use it as `this['name' /* + subTask.Id */].focus()`.

---

However, Im not 100% sure if that could be the cause of your issue, especially because you didn't let us know if `console.log(this.refs)` actually has correct elements and if you didn't make mistakes.

Let me know how it works out for you.

---

I don't recommend to use jQuery, in other words: don't mix avoidable imperative code with declarative code. It seems like an easy solution for your issues but if you'll get the whole point of React, you'll understand that jQuery is not the easy solution, especially in long run.